# Why do we need a "root" scene in react native router flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am implementing a routing library for my app, one that seems to be really good is [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) they have good docs and implementation, I just have one question.

In all their examples, scenes are wrapped in a root scene, so:

```
<Scene key="root">
  <Scene key="sceneOne" component={SceneOne} />
  <Scene key="sceneOne" component={SceneTwo} />
</Scene>
```

I have tried using it without root scene and it still works as expected:

```
<Scene key="sceneOne" component={SceneOne} />
<Scene key="sceneOne" component={SceneTwo} />
```

Hence my question, as I currently don't understand purpose of the root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're creating your scenes simply by adding them under your `<Router>` element, then you don't necessarily need a root element. For example, the following would work:

```
  render() {
    return <Router>
        <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
        <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register"/>
        <Scene key="home" component={Home}/>
    </Router>
  }
```

However, if you're creating your scenes using `Actions.create()` then you need a root element because *adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag*. For example (taken by the library's doc):

```
import {Actions, Scene, Router} from 'react-native-router-flux';

const scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
    <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register"/>
    <Scene key="home" component={Home}/>
  </Scene>
);

/* ... */

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Router scenes={scenes}/>
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any other reasons?

Comment: There can be several other good reasons for doing this but it would depend on the situation. For example, one reason to have a root element is to add props that should be the same for all underlining children, eg set a common style for the NavBar using the `navigationBarStyle` prop.

Comment: your first solution with mutiple Scenes in the Router does not work anymore. The Router should contain only one Scene.